# iOS: Modify mic data stream with audio unit?

Tags: ios

Could someone explain in terms of Audio Unit connections how to modify the iPhone microphone data stream visible to other processes with gain or EQ? I understand how to use a remote I/O unit to grab mic data and do my processing. I want this new data to replace the original mic data stream, not go to speakers or a file. "Audio Unit Hosting Fundamentals" Figure 1-3 is close.

I have read everything out there on Audio Units and used several of the online examples (Tim B, Play It Loud, Tasty Pixel) but don't see how to do this yet.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be clearly  explained or illustrated in the documentation. However, if you look at the AURIOTOUCH sample code, you will see how within the remote I/O render callback, it makes a call to retrieve data from the microphone.   then it optionally processes this data, and returns it.

this is kind of doubly useful because this call to retrieve microphone data returns already created buffesr. this means you don't have to create your own buffers, which is great becaues that is a bit of a hassle.